# Selenium сделать так что бы страница сразу открывалась с моим кодом html

Tags: c#, html, selenium

Помогите сделать так что бы при открытии страницы в Selenium код менялся сразу, а не после прогрузки всей страницы.
Сейчас делаю так:

```
driver.Url = ("https://google.com");

driver.ExecuteScript("document.documentElement.innerHTML = \"Hello World\";");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё работает, но сначала загружается страница гугла, как в примере. Потом уже всё меняется на мой код.
Помогите сделать так что бы страница сразу открывалась с моим кодом. Через прокси или hosts не вариант, спасибо!
В идеале что бы ещё и все скрипты JS работали.

Comment: Это не возможно. Зачем это нужно?

Comment: Возможно, могу показать пример работы, но нет исходного кода.

Comment: Зачем это нужно? От этого зависит более точный ответ, что возможно а что нет.